# Screen resize function - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make jquery do something if my screen width is less than 960 pixels I want to fire the width() - 140, if screen grater than 960px it should change width() - 340. If any other solution to achieve this always welcome.

```js
function resize() { 
  if ($(window).width() < 960) { 
    $(".test").css({
      width: $(window).width() - 140, 
      height: $(window).height() - 140,
    }); 
  }
    else () { 
      $(".test").css({
        width: $(window).width() - 340, 
        height: $(window).height() - 40,
      }); 
    }  
  resize(); 
  $(window).resize(function(){ resize(); });
```

```css
.test {
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Think **media queries** ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: So check the width.....Add an if

Comment: function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
            $(".test").css({
            width:  $(window).width() - 140,
            height: $(window).height() - 140
        });
    else ()
    {
     $(".test").css({
            width:  $(window).width() - 340,
            height: $(window).height() - 040
        });
    }
        }
         resize();
        $(window).resize(function(){
         resize();
        });

Comment: @LcSalazar i need JS solution.

Answer (score 2):

IF you really need to use jQuery for targeting certain resolution, this should do:

**[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdp69L1L/5/)**

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width:960px)");
mq.addListener(WidthChange);
WidthChange(mq);

function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
      $(".test").css({'width':'140px', 'height':'140px'});
  } else {
      $(".test").css({'width':'340px' , 'height':'40px'});
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
background: green;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test"></div>
```

Otherwise I recommend using CSS Media Queries which is faster:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdp69L1L/4/)

```css
.test {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 340px;
  height:40px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .test {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: The provided code does the same thing. As you describe in your question: if the screen is less than 960px. Both examples in my answer do the same.

Comment: I don't want external css to change to element style.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @media for css instead of jquery/javascript code, if your goal is to make different padding/margin for different window width.

Comment: No. I need only JS solution.

Comment: @Azzah, in that case take a look above, Nima gave you the most right solution. As for me, save constants in js code, not good idea, if you need to change margins/padding only.

Comment: No. I have change some other properties to. I need only JS solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cou can do this with pure css and [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

http://jsfiddle.net/hwgnmmc7/

```css
.test {
    width: calc( 100% - 140px );
    height: calc( 100% - 140px );
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
}
@media(min-width:960px) {
    .test {
        width: calc( 100% - 340px );
        height: calc( 100% - 340px )
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you code as follows:

```
  function resize() 
  { 
    var width = $(window).width();

    var offset_w = width + (width > 960 : 340 : 140);
    var offset_h = $(window).height() + (width > 960 : 140 : 40);

      $(".test").css({
        width: offset_w, 
        height: offset_h,
      }); 
  }
```